# With Spring Cloud - Brixton.M1, random port not registered with Eureka

Tags: spring-cloud

With Angel.SR3, assigning server.port: 0 would assign a random port to embedded Tomcat instance and use that port when registering with Eureka (using random instance ID as well in order to run more than one instance of a service on my dev machine).

I want to use the new Spring Cloud Sleuth for automatic tracing so first I just tried using spring-cloud-starter-sleuth at 1.0.0.M1 but trace and span didn't show up in log files when using the logging pattern in the example app.  I thought it might be related to the versions of the other libraries that I was picking up with Angel.SR3 so I tried experimenting with Brixton.M1.  With Brixton.M1, trace and span are now being set correctly but my service no longer registers its random port with Eureka - port 0 is registered instead.  Tomcat DOES come up on a random port, however.

I added a breakpoint in EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.containerPortInitializer() and it is not hit until AFTER the service has registered with Eureka Server in Brixton.M1 and is hit BEFORE service registration in Angel.SR3.

Am I missing something or is this currently broken in Brixton.M1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/570) that has been fixed in snapshots. Another milestone will come in the next week or so.

Comment: I tried with 1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and the problem still persists.  Should the fix be in that build?

Comment: Something else changed since the fix was put in that is causing this not to work. What is your use case? This is really for testing only.

Comment: The use case is a multi-instance setup on my laptop.  Ultimately service instances will be deployed on their own nodes, but during development it is very convenient to be able to run service instances from within IntelliJ.  I know I could run multiple instance locally using Docker or something similar, but it's not nearly as convenient when actively working on the services.

Comment: The obvious workaround is to set sever.port to non-conflicting ports.

Comment: I meant multiple instance of the same service type.  The workaround I can use is profiles with different ports.

Comment: You don't NEED profiles, you could use `--server.port=xxxx`, but, basically it gets the job done.

Comment: Ah. You meant on the command line.  That would work, too.  I thought you meant the properties file.

Comment: I've got a fix that I want @DaveSyer too look at before I merge: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/pull/611